# Is it possible to make tab completion work for argument prompt?

Tags: powershell

Default argument completer for string argument is just a path.

However, if required argument is not supplied, user is presented with the prompt to enter argument value, but tab completion is not working in that case.

Is it possible to enable it for the prompt as well?

Comment: The automatic prompts for mandatory parameters are bare-bones, unfortunately - see [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/4068#issuecomment-395931178).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to enable [file system tab-completion] for the prompt as well?

That depends entirely on the host application!

## In the default host applications: No!

The prompt implementation in the default host applications (`powershell.exe`/`pwsh.exe`) are kept extremely simple for easy interoperability with legacy command line applications.

When the host application prompts for missing arguments, it's really *last-resort exception avoidance* - the caller failed to supply mandatory parameter arguments for the code they asked to invoke, and the command processor intervenes by asking the host application "Please, interrupt everything and try to give me *some* input, otherwise I can't proceed" - and the simplest way of implementing this intervention in a way that's compatible with the I/O characteristics of most command line tools is to just block until an input string is provided via `stdin`.

---

## In a custom host application: Sure!

If you're interested in [developing your own host application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/hosting/creating-a-custom-user-interface?view=powershell-7) to sit atop PowerShell's language engine, you can use whatever UI flow you want, as long as your host applications UI implements [`Prompt()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.host.pshostuserinterface.prompt?view=powershellsdk-7.0.0#System_Management_Automation_Host_PSHostUserInterface_Prompt_System_String_System_String_System_Collections_ObjectModel_Collection_System_Management_Automation_Host_FieldDescription__) as a synchronous method that returns a dictionary of `parameterName<->argument` bindings.

There's even [an official sample application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/hosting/host04-sample) showing a rudimentary `PSHostUserInterface` implementation with custom `Prompt()` and `PromptForChoice()` to get you started!